# VeeValidate - required_if based on a method

Tags: vue.js, vee-validate

I have the following code:

```
<ValidationProvider
  ref="companyName"
  v-slot="{ errors }"
  :immediate="shouldValidate('companyName')"
  required_if="!isPrivate"
>
  <TextInput
    v-model="companyName"
    type="text"
    placeholder="Business Name"
    :data-saved="companyName.length > 0"
    :validate="true"
    :errors="errors"
  />
```

And I also have a method that checks whether a condition is true or not.

```
get isPrivate(): boolean {
return this.customerTypeStore.isDefault }
```

I would like to be able to toggle the required validation depending on whether isPrivate is true or not. I.e if it's not private, then the field is not required. But I can't get it working.

Is there a way in VeeValidate to use methods to achieve this?